# PLPGSQL function returns ERROR: integer out of range even if value is correct

Tags: postgresql, function, plpgsql, postgresql-13

I'm experiencing strange behaviour on two Postgres functions returning a single bigint value. The first one returns the correct value while the second one throws an error:

> ERROR: integer out of range

The only difference is that the first one returns a constant time value in ns, while the second one calculates it based on constant values, for convenience, given in s:

This one works fine:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c_getTime1()
RETURNS bigint AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN 12000000000; --12s in ns
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE parallel safe;
```

This one throws an error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION c_getTime2()
RETURNS bigint AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN 12*1000*1000*1000; --12s in ns
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE parallel safe;
```

Just wondering, is there any big difference? Should I somehow type-cast the second function's return?
Both functions are called using direct way:

```
select c_getTime1();
select c_getTime2();
```

The Postgresql database version is 13.3.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select pg_typeof(100);
return `integer`.
`RETURN 12*1000*1000*1000;`  will first compute as **integer** then cast to bigint.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html
first compute then found out `ERROR:  22003: integer out of range`
so you should change to

`RETURN 12 ::bigint * 1000 ::bigint * 1000::bigint * 1000::bigint;`

Comment: All you need to do is: `select 12*1000*1000*1000::bigint; 12000000000`